# When copying selected text extra text is copied, How does it work?

Tags: javascript, html

Often on some sites when you copy text, like a poem site. Text beyond what you have selected also gets copied. For example

```
Poem poem p..
Poem poem p..
Poem poem p..
Poem poem p..

/*more poems can be found at http://www.poems.com */
```

How does this work. Even though i only copied the Poem poem p.. parts and it wasn't even on the page, at least not visible.